# Calling right block in Magento 1.6.2 of static html

Tags: html, magento, static-block

I am creating a CMS page in magento as a teaser for an upcoming product.  I am using two columns with a right bar and using the layout update XML in the backend to call some custom blocks I make for the right side.

Well right now I am loading just placeholders then going to edit the phtmls after the fact.

If I use two blocks on the right it looks fine.. but if I add more, then the whole footer corrupts and moves to the right column.

I am trying to get 3 custom blocks on the right side.

Here is my layout update XML

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/rightsubscribe.phtml"/>
<block type="core/template" name="name1" template="page/custom/custom1.phtml"/>
<block type="core/template" name="name2" template="page/custom/custom2.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Here is the HTML of the customs blocks I am using.

```
<div id="shop-with-confidence" class="white-box">
    <h3>Custom1</h3>
    <div class="white-box-inner">
         Testing1
    </div>


    <div id="shop-with-confidence" class="white-box">
    <h3>Custom2</h3>
    <div class="white-box-inner">
         Testing2
    </div>
```

Does anyone have any idea why that would be wrecking the page I am editing?

Comment: Since I am a newb and cant answer my own question on here yet!

Comment: Man this is bad. After about 4 hours of troubleshooting and reading way to many magento XML docs it was simply missing the closing divs on each file.

I was initially thinking I couldn't use two of the same block types of the core/template variety, and obviously reading way to much into it.

div oversight FTL.

Comment: Yes, this was going to be my suggestion, as it's the only possible option.

Answer (score 0):

OP has already resolved the issue for himself, but it's worth noting that one can easily check parent-child block relationships to determine if an issue is framework- or markup- related.

To check the list of child blocks which a parent block has, one can simply do the following in a template:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getChild()) //list of children
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getSortedChildren()) //list of ordered children
```

In the case of blocks lacking templates (`core/text_list`, e.g. "right"), one could do this from a child block template as well:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getParentBlock()->getChild()) //list of children
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getParentBlock()->getSortedChildren()) //list of ordered children
```

Ref [`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php) for more information.